# Arcs in the picture environment

Tags: diagrams

Two rays go out from a vertex, with a 37-degree angle between them. Between them near the vertex one does this:

\put(27,70){$37^\circ$}

But then one wishes to enclose that within an arc centered at the vertex of the angle and ending at the two rays. That is often done in such diagrams. How can it be coded?

[image: angle]

Comment: Could you please add a small sketch of what you want?

Comment: @caverac : Here's one that puts the degree specifications outside the arc rather than inside, and has some other imperfections. I'll see if I can find a better one: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_angle#/media/File:Remint3.svg

Comment: please, provide what you try so far. small, complete document with picture of triangle will simplify to show you, how to solve your problem.

Comment: @MichaelHardy, any news?

Comment: @Zarko : I've set this aside for a few days but I'll probably get back to it within 48 hours.

Answer (score 3):

with `tikz`:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{angles, quotes}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) coordinate (A) -- ++ (2,0) coordinate (B);
\draw (A) -- ++ (37:2) coordinate (C);
\pic [draw,angle radius=9mm, angle eccentricity=1.5, "$\SI{37}{\degree}$"] {angle = B--A--C};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, this is the way this should be done in the year 2018. (+1) I was just under the the impression that the OP was using pstricks, which is also cool.

Comment: @marmot, thank you for nice comment. actually i wrote my answer as `tikz` supplement to your `pstrick` solution (+1 for it).

Comment: Turns out he was using the old `picture` environment. This was before pictex, if I remember correctly. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

This is just an answer to what I thought your original questions was.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\begin{document}
\psset{unit=0.1}
\begin{pspicture}(20,65)(50,80)
\psline{-}(20,68)(50,68)
\put(27,70){$37^\circ$}
\psarc{-}(20,68){6.5}{0}{37}
\rput{37}(20,68){\psline{-}(0,0)(30,0)}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, you can have the `37 degrees` inside the arc as well.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\begin{document}
\psset{unit=0.1}
\begin{pspicture}(20,65)(50,80)
\psline{-}(20,68)(50,68)
\put(27,70){$37^\circ$}
\psarc{-}(20,68){14}{0}{37}
\rput{37}(20,68){\psline{-}(0,0)(30,0)}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

It's been a really long time since I've been using the LaTeX `picture` environment. Here is something which almost certainly cannot be confused with the Sistine Chapel ;-)

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\setlength{\unitlength}{0.1cm}
\begin{picture}(20,65)(50,80)
\put(5,10){\line(1,3){30}} 
\put(5,10){\line(2,1){40}}
\put(17,28){$37^\circ$}
\qbezier(15,40)(25,38)(25,20)
\end{picture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

It is not even a real arc. You can play with the second coordinate in `\qbezier`. The first and last coordinates were "derived" from the lines by just adding 10 times the line slope to `(5,0)`.

Comment: I now see that I neglected a certain complication: Suppose the lines are specified by slopes rather than by degrees, thus: \put(5,10){\line(1,3){30}} and \put(5,10){\line(2,1){40}}. Your code contains the number 37, which I presume means that's the angular length of the arc. But what if it is to be bounded by the slopes specified by (1,3) and (2,1) in the commands appearing in this comment? Must one compute the number of degrees and code it as in your answer above, or can one use those slopes somehow?

Comment: @MichaelHardy You can but I need to know which tools you are using. From your original code I *guessed* you're using pstricks, but from what I see now I'm wondering if you're using some very old pictex or so. Please let me know!

Comment: The only \usepackage command before \begin{document} in the LaTeX file I'm editing is for a style file that does not contain the sequences pict or pst, and the only \usepackage command within that file is \usepackage{times}.

Comment: . . . . . and at the moment I'm just trying to get some simple pictures drawn rather than prepare in case I'm ever commissioned to paint the ceiling of the Sistine Chapel with LaTeX.

Comment: @MichaelHardy I guess that in the picture environment it will be nontrivial to draw a perfect arc.

Comment: So you're saying I should use pstricks?

Comment: @MichaelHardy Depending on what you want to do, I personally would recommend either Ti*k*Z, PSTricks or asymptote. As long as you're not interested in real 3D features, Ti*k*Z is IMHO the most powerful tool that is available. If you're mainly interested in 3D, go for asymptote. PSTricks is still (IMHO) a bit better in 3D than Ti*k*Z and easier to use than asymptote (since you're not required to run `asy`), so if you want to have one tool for everything, go for PSTricks. I personally use T*k*Z for 2D and asymptote for 3D, but I was very happy with PSTricks for a long time.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(5,5)
\psline(4,0)(0,0)(4;37)
\rput(2;18.5){$37^\circ$}
\psarc(0,0){1.5}{0}{37}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

or

```
\rput(1;18.5){$37^\circ$}
```

for an inside label

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A very short code with `pst-eucl`, from the `pstricks` family:

```
\documentclass[svgnames]{article}

\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\usepackage{siunitx} 
% \usepackage{auto-pst-pdf} %% To compile with pdflatex --enablewrite18 (MiKTeX) or pdflatex --shell-escape (TeX Live, MacTeX)

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\psset{unit=3, linejoin = 1}
\everypsbox{\footnotesize}
\begin{pspicture}(0,-0.1)(1,1)
\pstGeonode[ PointName = none, PointSymbol = none] (0,0){O}(1,0){A}(1; 37){B}
\pstMarkAngle[linecolor = Gold, MarkAngleRadius = 0.3, LabelSep = 0.42]{A}{O}{B}{\SI{37}{\degree}}
\psline[linecolor = IndianRed](A)(O)(B)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]